# Is Chrome available on any Win8 phones?

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, internet-explorer, phone

I have a Nokia Lumia 520

I hate IE.

I really want Chrome.

There seem to be a few knock-off versions of Chrome on the Windows Store.

Is there an official version?

Is Chrome available on any Win8 phones?

Comment: Questions about electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill. Is there an appropriate exchange for these topics?

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology shows all of the tech sites. I guess you want http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DavidPostill cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately no,

The closest thing is a [google browser](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/google/220bfbf2-ee02-496c-a656-651a6c0c6518) but it is very crappy.

You might as well pin the google mobile page to your home screen.